# User selection copied to clipboard from HTML table introduces Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table displaying a part number, with individual components in different `<td></td>`. When users select/highlight the row, they can copy the part number and paste wherever they would like.

However, the part number is then pasted with tabs representing where the different `<td>` cells were between characters.

How can I make it such that users select the table row and get a clean (no tabs) version of the part number?

```html
<table class="abPartNum">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>Series Designator</th>
    <th></th><th>Rows</th>
    <th>Body Style</th>
    <th>Body Material</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Contact Type</th>
    <th>Contact Plating</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Hardware Style</th>
    <th>Polarization</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="pnCell">MK</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td class="pnCell">2</td>
    <td class="pnCell">5</td>
    <td class="pnCell">2</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td class="pnCell">009</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td class="pnCell">32</td>
    <td class="pnCell">3</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td class="pnCell">22</td>
    <td class="pnCell">0R</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td class="pnCell">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Result of copy and paste:
`MK -   2   5   2   -   009 -   32  3   -   22  0R`

Desired result:
`MK-252-009-323-22-0R`

Comment: Could you also post the related jQuery?

Comment: (If there is any yet. It's still an answerable question if there isn't any! So no worry.)

Comment: There's no jquery (yet), user is simply using cursor to select the second table row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can simply instruct the user to click anywhere in the table row, this will get you there:

```js
$('td').click(function(){
  var txt = $(this).parent().children().text()

  $("#result").text(txt)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table, td { border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
<table class="abPartNum">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Series Designator</th><th></th><th>Rows</th><th>Body Style</th><th>Body Material</th><th></th><th>Size</th><th></th><th>Contact Type</th><th>Contact Plating</th><th></th><th>Hardware Style</th><th>Polarization</th><th></th><th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pnCell">MK</td><td>-</td><td class="pnCell">2</td><td class="pnCell">5</td><td class="pnCell">2</td><td>-</td><td class="pnCell">009</td><td>-</td><td class="pnCell">32</td><td class="pnCell">3</td><td>-</td><td class="pnCell">22</td><td class="pnCell">0R</td><td>-</td><td class="pnCell"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p id="result"></p>
```

*(Note: I had edited this to include the [`copy` event's `setData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy), but my tests show it is buggy, at least on Firefox, and so back to the simple version.)*

Comment: Delightfully simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to concatenate the values in these cells into a value that can be copied by the user in the format you require in an additional column in the table. eg:

HTML tidied up as follows:

```
<style type="">

td {border: solid 1px black;}
th {padding:10px;}
</style>
<table class="abPartNum" style="border:solid 1px black;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Series Designator</th>
<th>Rows</th>
<th>Body Style</th>
<th>Body Material</th>

<th>Size</th>

<th>Contact Type</th>
<th>Contact Plating</th>

<th>Hardware Style</th>
<th>Polarization</th>

<th>Options</th>
<th>Complete code</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="pnCell">MK</td>

<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td class="pnCell">5</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>

<td class="pnCell">009</td>

<td class="pnCell">32</td>
<td class="pnCell">3</td>

<td class="pnCell">22</td>
<td class="pnCell">0R</td>

<td class="pnCell">
</td>
<td class="complete"></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Then using the following javascript

```
<script>
    var completeCells = document.getElementsByClassName("complete");

    for (item in completeCells){

        var Options = completeCells[item].previousElementSibling;
        var Polarization = Options.previousElementSibling;
        var HardwareStyle = Polarization.previousElementSibling;
        var ContactPlating = HardwareStyle.previousElementSibling;
        var ContactType = ContactPlating.previousElementSibling;
        var Size = ContactType.previousElementSibling;
        var BodyMaterial = Size.previousElementSibling;
        var BodyStyle = BodyMaterial.previousElementSibling;
        var Rows = BodyStyle.previousElementSibling;
        var SeriesDesignator = Rows.previousElementSibling;

        completeCells[item].innerHTML = SeriesDesignator.innerHTML + "-" + Rows.innerHTML + "-" + BodyStyle.innerHTML + "-" + BodyMaterial.innerHTML + "-" + Size.innerHTML + "-" + ContactType.innerHTML + "-" + HardwareStyle.innerHTML + "-" + Polarization.innerHTML + "-" + Options.innerHTML; 

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser support on this might be a little sketchy : https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

You can use the clipboard API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData

Unlike other answers this actually adjusts the data in the clipboard if you are copying outside the browser.

```js
$(".abPartNum").on("copy", function(e){
    
    //Get selected data and remove white space
    var pastedData = window.getSelection().toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
    
    //Set the clipboard data
    if (window.clipboardData) {
      //Handle IEs non standard implemtation
      window.clipboardData.setData('text', pastedData);
    }else{
    
    (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData).setData("text", pastedData);    
    }
    
    //Prevent the normal copy from happening
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //For Debugging
    console.log(pastedData);
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="abPartNum">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Series Designator</th>
<th></th><th>Rows</th>
<th>Body Style</th>
<th>Body Material</th>
<th></th>
<th>Size</th>
<th></th>
<th>Contact Type</th>
<th>Contact Plating</th>
<th></th>
<th>Hardware Style</th>
<th>Polarization</th>
<th></th>
<th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="pnCell">MK</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td class="pnCell">5</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">009</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">32</td>
<td class="pnCell">3</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">22</td>
<td class="pnCell">0R</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Paste Here:
<textarea></textarea>
```

This might be a better User Experience though

```js
$(".abPartNum tbody tr").on("click", function(e){    
    $(".abPartNum tbody tr").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var pastedData = $(this).children().text();
    $("#tmpCode").val(pastedData).select();
    
    //initiate copy
    document.execCommand('copy');  
    
    //For Debugging
    console.log(pastedData);
} );
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #CCF;
}

#tmpCode {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Cick on table row to copy Part Number
<table class="abPartNum">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Series Designator</th>
<th></th><th>Rows</th>
<th>Body Style</th>
<th>Body Material</th>
<th></th>
<th>Size</th>
<th></th>
<th>Contact Type</th>
<th>Contact Plating</th>
<th></th>
<th>Hardware Style</th>
<th>Polarization</th>
<th></th>
<th>Options</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="pnCell">MK</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td class="pnCell">5</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">009</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">32</td>
<td class="pnCell">3</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">22</td>
<td class="pnCell">0R</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="pnCell">MK</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td class="pnCell">5</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">009</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">32</td>
<td class="pnCell">3</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">22</td>
<td class="pnCell">0R</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">01
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="pnCell">MK</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td class="pnCell">5</td>
<td class="pnCell">2</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">009</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">32</td>
<td class="pnCell">3</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">23</td>
<td class="pnCell">0R</td>
<td>-</td>
<td class="pnCell">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input id="tmpCode" />

Paste Here:
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Yeep. I had tried putting that in, trusting the MDN docs, and it was a no-go. CanIUse paints a whole scarier picture. (But yours does work on FF for me.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this might be to create a copy button on every row of the table for every code that can be copied. In one of the row's cells, include an input field with a value of the code for the row, and give it an opacity of 0 to hide it. You can then link the copy button to the input field using the same code for its id. When the copy button is clicked, it then uses the JavaScript select() function to copy the value of the input field, and then uses the execCommand("copy") to send the selected code to the clip board:

```js
function copyText(copyId) {
  var copyCode = document.getElementById(copyId);
  copyCode.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```css
.textToCopy {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="abPartNum">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Series Designator</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Rows</th>
      <th>Body Style</th>
      <th>Body Material</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Contact Type</th>
      <th>Contact Plating</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Hardware Style</th>
      <th>Polarization</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Options</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pnCell">MK</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td class="pnCell">2</td>
      <td class="pnCell">5</td>
      <td class="pnCell">2</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td class="pnCell">009</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td class="pnCell">32</td>
      <td class="pnCell">3</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td class="pnCell">22</td>
      <td class="pnCell">0R</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td class="pnCell">
      </td>
      <td><button onClick="copyText('MK-252-009-323-220R')">Copy code</button><input id="MK-252-009-323-220R" class="textToCopy" value="MK-252-009-323-220R"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```